# Check if two Facebook users are friends with one request to Facebook servers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Users on my app login from their device. They then send to my application server their access token, and a userid of a friend. I do not trust this information so I need to verify that these users are really friends. Following the docs from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends I can make an a request such as:

```
GET /v2.5/{user-id-a}/friends/{user-id-b} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

So it looks like I need the user id of the user first. Do I need to make a request to Facebook first using the accesstoken to get the userid and then send another request using the this userid to make sure the user are friends or can I skip the first step somehow? Instead of making two requests can I use the accesstoken somehow to only make one request to Facebook to just see if the users are friends (Facebook somehow derives the userid from the access token automatically)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/me/friends/{user-id-b}
```

You should always use `/me` instead of the user ID anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Sorry, but I just realized it doesn't work. I am sending this from a server, not the client. The user logs in from the client, but my server sends the http reques to facebook. All my server gets from the client is the access token.

Comment: it does not matter, you need to use a user token for that, and /me points to the profile of the user who owns the user token.

Comment: Ohh, I wasen't passing the the access token in the request url. Thanks!